# Does pthread_rwlockattr_getkind_np() just returns the flag set using pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am using pthread rwlock and trying to change rwlock behavior to give priority to waiting writer. From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np.3.html) looks like following snippet should be enough.

```
        pthread_rwlock_t rwlock;
        pthread_rwlockattr_t attr;
        pthread_rwlockattr_init(&attr);        //default attributes
        pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np(&attr, PTHREAD_RWLOCK_PREFER_WRITER_NONRECURSIVE_NP);     //preference for writer
        pthread_rwlock_init(&rwLock, &attr);   //use that attribute to create new rwlock
```

What is the purpose of pthread_rwlockattr_getkind_np() then? Is it to just return the flag that was passed to pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np()?

Comment: How does http://www.kerrisk.com/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_rwlockattr_getkind_np.3.html not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of pthread_rwlockattr_getkind_np() then? Is it to just return the flag that was passed to pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np()?

Yes, or the initial value that was set via `pthread_rwlockattr_init()`, as applicable.